# memcache doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, memcached

We have a small application for Google App Engine in Python, and we are using memcache. But memcache keys remain even after memcache.delete, and also memcache returns a number (0) when I expect it to return a string ("undefined"). Here is my code:

**check_feature.py:**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')

import webapp2
import json
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from models.shard_counter import GeneralCounterShard
from models.check_feature_limit import CheckFeatureLimit


class CheckFeatureHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get_number_of_users_enabled(self, feature_name):
        """
        Get the number of users enabled for the given feature name.
        """
        number_of_users_enabled_undefined = "undefined"
        number_of_users_enabled = memcache.get(key=feature_name)
        if (number_of_users_enabled is None):
            check_feature_limit = None
            check_feature_limits = CheckFeatureLimit.gql("WHERE feature_name=:1 ORDER BY last_modified DESC LIMIT 1", feature_name)
            if (check_feature_limits.count() > 0):
                check_feature_limit = check_feature_limits.get()
            if (check_feature_limit):
                number_of_users_enabled = check_feature_limit.number_of_users_enabled
            if (number_of_users_enabled is None):
                number_of_users_enabled = number_of_users_enabled_undefined
            memcache.add(key=feature_name, value=number_of_users_enabled, time=3600)
        if (number_of_users_enabled == number_of_users_enabled_undefined):
            number_of_users_enabled = None
        return number_of_users_enabled
```

**admin.py:**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'libs')

import webapp2
import json
import requests
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from models.shard_counter import GeneralCounterShard
from models.check_feature_limit import CheckFeatureLimit

template.register_template_library("tags.tags")


class AdminHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.post()

    def post(self):
        params = {}
        number_of_users_enabled_dict = {}
        number_of_users_dict = {}
        r = requests.get(url="http://jsons.[part_of_link_suppressed].com.s3.amazonaws.com/flags.json")
        flags = json.loads(r.text)
        if ((flags) and ("depending_on_counter" in flags) and (len(flags["depending_on_counter"]) > 0)):
            for feature_name in flags["depending_on_counter"]:
                check_feature_limit = None
                check_feature_limits = CheckFeatureLimit.gql("WHERE feature_name=:1 ORDER BY last_modified DESC LIMIT 1", feature_name)
                if (check_feature_limits.count() > 0):
                    check_feature_limit = check_feature_limits.get()
                number_of_users_enabled = self.request.get(feature_name + "_number_of_users_enabled")
                if (number_of_users_enabled):
                    number_of_users_enabled = int(number_of_users_enabled)
                    if (not(check_feature_limit)):
                        check_feature_limit = CheckFeatureLimit(feature_name=feature_name)
                    check_feature_limit.number_of_users_enabled = number_of_users_enabled
                    check_feature_limit.put()
                    memcache.delete(key=feature_name) # I don't think it works.
                number_of_users_enabled = None
                if (check_feature_limit):
                    number_of_users_enabled = check_feature_limit.number_of_users_enabled
                if (not(number_of_users_enabled is None)):
                    number_of_users_enabled_dict[feature_name] = number_of_users_enabled
                number_of_users = GeneralCounterShard.get_count(feature_name)
                number_of_users_dict[feature_name] = number_of_users
            params["depending_on_counter"] = flags["depending_on_counter"]
            params["number_of_users_enabled_dict"] = number_of_users_enabled_dict
            params["number_of_users_dict"] = number_of_users_dict
        html = template.render("admin/admin.html", params)
        self.response.out.write(html)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ("/admin", AdminHandler)
], debug=True)
```

The values of test_counter_feature_1 (Number of users to enable) is 2, test_counter_feature_2 is 4 and test_counter_feature_3 is undefined (there is no object), but in the memcache the values are 2, 3 and 0 respectively, even after I save the form (and therefore the memcache should be deleted). What is the problem? I expect the value of test_counter_feature_3 to be "undefined", not 0. And the two other values should be deleted after saving the form.

Comment: Can you reduce this to a minimal testcase please? I don't think we need the whole project here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, I removed the irrelevant code. Please focus on the lines containing "memcache", especially "memcache.delete".

Comment: It's still far away from a minimal test case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the problem. `GeneralCounterShard` also saved the same key to memcache, so I renamed the key and everything works now. The new key is `feature_name + "_number_of_users_enabled"`, instead of `feature_name` like it was before. So I replaced all the calls to memcache with the new key, and now it works. Thank you!